# Sizing of Facebook dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-opengraph

When using the new Facebook Feed Dialog with the display=iframe, how do you control the size?  There are no parameters for size listed on the doc page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ and the shadow box is filling my entire canvas.

Answer (score 0):

FB.UIServer.Methods["feed"] = {size:{width:450,height:240}};

put this right after your fb.init.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Methods' of undefined